# Url.Action is member of..?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Url.Action found in MVC is member of what classes? VS2008 cannot find it and keeps offering me just System.Security.Policy to import. Alternatively, can I make ActionLink helper NOT to encode it's content, so this code would work:

```
sb.Append(helper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName, new{onclick=""}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper

Answer (score 0):

Please see [`System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.aspx) (found in `System.Web.Mvc.dll`):

> Contains methods for building URLs for
>   ASP.NET MVC within your application.